# Gamma Distribution vs Convolution of 2 Exponential Random Variables.

Tags: probability-distributions

If X and Y are 2 independent random variables with Exponential($\lambda$) distributions, my understanding is that their convolution (Z = X + Y) is given by:

$f_Z(z) = -\lambda ze^{-\lambda z}$

The convolution formula is supposed to be:
$f_Z(z) = \int_0^z f_X(z-w)f_Y(w) dy$
$ = \int_0^z \lambda e^{-\lambda (z-w)} \lambda  e^{-\lambda (w)} dy$
$ = \int_0^z \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z} dy$
$ = \lambda^2 y e^{-\lambda z}$  evaluated on $[0, z]$
$ = \lambda^2 z e^{-\lambda z}$

This is supposed to be equivalent to the Gamma Distribution given by: $$\frac{\lambda^2 z^{\alpha-1}}{(\alpha - 1) !}e^{-\lambda z}$$ with $\alpha = 2$

What happened to the -ve sign in $-\lambda$?
Nothing, I made a mistake in the integration.

Comment: If the question is how your computations led (wrongly) to $-\lambda$ instead of $\lambda^2$ then you ought to show these computations, no?

Comment: @Did, looks like I made a mistake in the computation of the integral. Thx!